# HttpSendRequest WININET stuck - takes long time to finish - WINDOWS XP

Tags: winapi, wininet

Hallo, i have serious problem with this wininet function, whe i run my program on windows 7, everything works perfectly, but when i try to use it on windows XP service pack 3. Sometimes it takes for HttpSendRequst too long time to finish and i really dont know why and sometimes for the same request, it finishes almost instantly. I am loading websites with my prog.

What is the difference between Win 7 and XP in wininet? I tried allmost everything but doesnt work. For example set time out for Httpsendrequest and repeat again or set maximum internet connections for more. But nothing seemed to work and the functionality was allways the same.

Please help if you can.

```
m_hInternet = InternetOpenA(m_strAgentName.c_str(), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG , 
            NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (!m_hInternet) {
        m_strLastError = "Cannot open internet";
        m_lastErrorCode = GetLastError();
        return false;
    }
m_hSession = InternetConnectA(m_hInternet, 
            m_strServerName.c_str(), 
            m_wPort,
            m_strUserName.c_str(), 
            m_strPassword.c_str(),
            INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,
            INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION,
            0);
m_hRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(m_hSession, 
            this->m_strMethod.c_str(),
            m_strObjectName.c_str(),
            NULL,
            m_strReferer != "" ? m_strReferer.c_str() : NULL,
            NULL,
            INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTO_REDIRECT | INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 
            m_ReqID);
bool result =  HttpSendRequestA(    m_hRequest,
                                    this->m_strAddHeaders.size() == 0 ? NULL : this->m_strAddHeaders.c_str(), 
                                    this->m_strAddHeaders.size(), 
                                    (char*)this->m_strContent.c_str(),
                                    this->m_strContent.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you check that request is completed successfully? There should be some response code with text. Otherwise your fast requests could be caused by abnormal termination.

If this is a complete code sample I’d suggest adding [HttpEndRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384230%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: the HttpEndRequest is only for httpSendRequestEx function as far as i know.

Comment: Opps, you are right… Anyway I would check that each request is completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem a couple of times when the request doesnt finish at all.

The only solution i have found to this is giving the program enough time between each request.

So you can use a buffer to store and add all the data and every X time you send it trough the request!

Comment: Could you elaborate why this is only necessary on Windows XP as was mentioned in the question? And could you provide a small code example of how what you mean with buffering data?

Comment: @NOhs I have encountered this on windows 7 aswel.